# Create a file and save it to a parent directory using PHP?

Tags: php, file, directory

How can i Create a file and save it to a parent directory?

So as you can see from my script below, the PHP saves the "referer.log" file to the same directory where this PHP is, but i want it to save to a parent directory?

This is my Current PHP:

```
<?php
$fname="referer.log";
$file=fopen($fname,'a+');
$url = "$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
fwrite($file,"

Referer: $url

");
fclose($file);
?>
```

Lets say my current directory is

> /forum/link/contact/

i want it to be saved on

> /forum/link/logs/

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Something like: $file=fopen('/forum/link/logs/' . $fname,'a+');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are free to use relative path:

```
$fname = "../logs/referer.log";
```

I would suggest you to check whether the directory exists and create it if it’s not:

```
if( !is_dir('../logs') ) {
  mkdir( '../logs', 0750, true );
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you everyone/ mudasobwa's answer worked! thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 Relative path
$fname="../logs/referer.log";

Option 2 Absolute path
dirname( dirname(**FILE**) )."/logs/referer.log";